# Consider the functions $f,g : \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ defined by $f(z)=e^z, g(z)=e^{iz}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I came across the following problem that says:

> Consider the functions $f,g\colon \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ defined by $f(z)=e^z, g(z)=e^{iz}$. Let $S=\{z \in \mathbb C:Re(z)\in [-\pi,\pi]\}.$ Then which of the following options is correct?
>
> $1$. $f$ is an onto entire function
>
> $2$. $g$ is a bounded function on $\mathbb C$
>
> $3$. $f$ is bounded on $S$
>
> $4$. $g$ is bounded on $S$

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What does $[-z, z]$ mean?

Comment: I'm sure that you meant something else than $[-z,z]$, since $S$ makes no sense as it is.

Comment: sorry for the mistake. I have edited it.

Comment: Thanks for remarking that point +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first statement, can you find $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z) = 0$? For the rest, use the fact that $$|e^z| = |e^{a+bi}| = |e^ae^{bi}| = |e^a||e^{bi}| = |e^a| = e^a = e^{\Re(z)}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.I have got it.

Comment: $f$ is bounded only

Comment: Why $e^{iz}$ is not bounded in $\mathbb{C}$ @LaBelleNoiseuse